# Firefox addon SDK: How to inject local .js file into certain website?

Tags: javascript, firefox, sdk

This may seem rather simple but I haven't found an answer for it yet. I know I have to use content script and pagemod and i know how to do it with remote file like jQuery CDN.

Answer (score 1):

An example for adding a script named my-script.js onto gmail would something like this:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*.mail.google.com",
    contentScriptFile: self.data.url("my-script.js"),
});
```

This snippet will go in your main.js file and my-script.js would go in your data folder after doing [cfx init](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_started).

Comment: I need the script to also be able to modify DOM and have variables. What you suggested is just using content script. I want to inject a .js WITH content script.

Comment: @user3729596 he is giving you the example you asked for.  `contentScriptFile` should contain the script you want injected into the web page.